# Why am I getting a gray screen when displaying a google map in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am not having any issues in Chrome, but I am having an issue is IE and Firefox.
here is my Javascript with the google maps.

I have read about doing a resize on the div, but I am not certain as to where I need to put this.

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBx_SYudvabOgIGRKueVJ7UUw3WIjexWg"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Control scrolling features
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
            }
        });

        var map, map2;

        var comm = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.regPoints));
        var cert = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.certPoints));
        var locations = [];
        var certLocs = [];
        var allMarkers = [];



        // Host
        var hostname = "/" + location.hostname;
        var host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
        if (hostname == "/localhost"){
            hostname = "";
            host = "";
        }

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        });

        // Map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -100.4179324),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        // Communities could be null if the Google maps is over the limit
        if (comm != null){
            for (i = 0; i < comm.length; i++) {
                var count = 0;
                var name = "";
                var lat = "";
                var long = "";
                var state = "";
                for (item in comm[i]) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1)
                        id = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 2)
                        name = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 3)
                        lat = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 4)
                        long = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 5)
                        state = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 6)
                        desc = comm[i][item];
                    if (count == 7)
                        population = comm[i][item];
                }
                locations.push({ name: name, latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), state: state, link: hostname + host + "Communities/CommunityPage/" + id, desc: desc, population: population });
            }
        }

        // Add the Markers to the map
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locations[i].latlng, map: map, title: locations[i].name,
                html: "<font color=" + "blue><strong>" + locations[i].state + "</strong></font><br />" +
                      "<a href=/" + locations[i].link +"><font color=red><strong>" + locations[i].name + "</strong></font></a>" +
                      "<p> Description: " + locations[i].desc +  "</p>" +
                      "<p> Population: " + locations[i].population + "</p>"
            });

            bounds.extend(locations[i].latlng);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function (marker) {
                return function (e) {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                }

            })(marker))

        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);


        function clickState(lat, lng, id) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            map.panTo(latLng);
        }

        function setCert(locs){

            if (locs == 0){
                $("#map2").addClass("hidden");
                $("#map").removeClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $("#map").addClass("hidden");
                $("#map2").removeClass("hidden");

                // Reset Map 2 Certified Locations
                var mapOptions2 = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -100.4179324),
                    zoom: 7,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

                map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), mapOptions2);

                if (cert != null){
                    for (i = 0; i < cert.length; i++) {
                        var count = 0;
                        var name = "";
                        var lat = "";
                        var long = "";
                        var state = "";
                        for (item in cert[i]) {
                            count++;
                            if (count == 1)
                                id = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 2)
                                name = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 3)
                                lat = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 4)
                                long = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 5)
                                state = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 6)
                                desc = cert[i][item];
                            if (count == 7)
                                population = cert[i][item];
                        }
                        certLocs.push({ name: name, latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), state: state, link: hostname + host + "Communities/CommunityPage/" + id, desc: desc, population: population });
                    }
                }

                // Add Certified Markers to the map

                // Add the Markers to the map
                var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < certLocs.length; i++) {

                    var iconBase = host + '/Css/cwhIcons/';
                    var icons = {
                        base: {
                            icon: iconBase + 'greenpin.png'
                        }
                    };

                    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: certLocs[i].latlng, map: map2, title: certLocs[i].name,
                        html: "<font color=" + "blue><strong>" + certLocs[i].state + "</strong></font><br />" +
                              "<a href=/" + certLocs[i].link +"><font color=red><strong>" + certLocs[i].name + "</strong></font></a>" +
                              "<p> Description: " + certLocs[i].desc +  "</p>" +
                              "<p> Population: " + certLocs[i].population + "</p>",
                        icon: icons['base'].icon
                    });

                    bounds2.extend(certLocs[i].latlng);
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", (function (marker2) {
                        return function (e) {
                            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                            infowindow.open(map2, this);
                        }
                    })(marker2))


                }

                map2.fitBounds(bounds2);

            }

        }

    </script>

}
```

Here is some markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" onclick="setCert(0);" data-toggle="tab">Registered</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="setCert(1);" data-toggle="tab">Certified</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">

                        @foreach (var st in Model.regCommunities)
                        {
                            <div class="dropdown">

                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@st.state</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                    @foreach (var pt in st.points)
                                    {
                                        <li role="presentation" onclick="clickState(@pt.latitude, @pt.longitude, @pt.CommunityId);"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="@Model.host/Communities/CommunityPage/@pt.CommunityId">@pt.CommunityName</a></li>
                                    }
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">

                        @foreach (var st in Model.cerCommunities)
                        {
                            <div class="dropdown">

                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@st.state</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                    @foreach (var pt in st.points)
                                    {
                                        <li role="presentation" onclick="clickState(@pt.latitude, @pt.longitude, @pt.CommunityId);"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="@Model.host/Communities/CommunityPage/@pt.CommunityId">@pt.CommunityName</a></li>
                                    }
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Map Legend:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
            <div id="map" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100%; height:500px"></div>
            <div id="map2" class="img-responsive hidden" style="width:720px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: none ... .it is bizzare